# La consola del lenguaje R aparece en alemán

Tags: r, consola

Comienzo a aprender *R*, acabo de instalar la consola, pero me aparece en alemán, no solo los mensajes en la consola, sino el mismo menú. ¿Qué puedo hacer? Lo estoy intentando en *MAC*.

Esta es la salida de la consola:

> Durante la inicialización - Warning messages:
>
> 1: Setting **LC_CTYPE** failed, using "C" 
> 2: Setting **LC_COLLATE** failed, using "C" 
> 3: Setting **LC_TIME** failed, using "C" 
> 4: Setting **LC_MESSAGES** failed, using "C" 
> 5: Setting **LC_MONETARY** failed, using "C"
>
> *[R.app GUI 11.66 (6956) x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0]*
>
> WARNUNG: Sie verwenden eine andere Umgebung als UTF-8, daher werden nur einfache Zeichen (ohne Umlaute) funktionieren.
>
> Bitte lesen Sie R for Mac OS X FAQ (siehe Hilfe) Sektion 9 und ändern Sie Ihre Einstellungen entsprechend.
>
> *[Verlauf wiederhergestellt aus /Users/FranciscoJ/.Rapp.history]*

Traducción del aleman al español:

> Advertencia: Usted está usando de un entorno diferente de *UTF-8*, por lo que sólo funcionan caracteres simples (sin diéresis).
>
> Por favor, lea el FAQ (ver ayuda) de *R* para *Mac OS X* en **Sección 9** y cambie la configuración en consecuencia.

Answer (score 1):

No deberías tener problemas simplemente debes fijar la lengua. Que no es lo mismo que la codificación que entiendo es lo que tú quieres también modificar.

```
Sys.setenv(LANG = "es")
```

En cuanto a los errores que te aparecen se refieren a codificaciones de R, las tienes en C entiendo por defecto. Yo no he usado habitualmente R en un MAC, pero sí que me paso en Linux el error que comentas con Sys.getlocale() verás tu configuración actual y si deseas establecerla en el formato español deberías ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "es_ES")
```